# query the same field multiple times in the same query

Tags: mysql

I need to filter a table in mysql but can't get past the beginning.
The table has 2 fields:

```
ID_house     house_feature
1            1
1            2
1            4
1            5
2            1
2            3
2            4
3            1
3            2
3            3
```

I need to filter this table using the following parameters:

```
house feature = 1
AND 
house feature = 2
AND 
house feature = 3
```

So that I get all houses with the requested feature.
I already tried to create something similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM houses
WHERE
house_feature = 1 
   AND 
house_feature = 2 
   AND 
house_feature = 3
```

But it doesn't work as I expected.
Is there a way to get this result with MySQL?
It seems that I acn filter the table using only the OR operator but this way I can't get the right result.

Thanks in advance for any help.

tony

Comment: what result you want get ?

Comment: You probably want to use `OR` - not `AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so ,by matching the distinct count of features per house ,so the house with exactly these 3 features will be returned

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE
house_feature  IN(1 ,2,3)
group by ID_house
having count(distinct house_feature) = 3
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6cec/1)

Comment: Seems to me a bit more sophisticated than what he wants, I believe that a simple: `SELECT *
FROM houses
WHERE
house_feature in (1,2,3)` will do

Comment: @alfasin i guess op wants the house which has exactly these 3 features not any one of them

Comment: you dont need distinct i guess.

Comment: @echo_Me i have added distinct only for the purpose that should validate these 3 features if OP added any feature twice then without distinct query will not result properly

Comment: yes if he have dupliacte values then its right, but its seems are not duplicated.